# How do I count a number of primes(say smaller than N) that does not contain 5?

Tags: counting

Title says it all.

How do I count a number of primes(say smaller than N) that does not contain 5?

Comment: Is this a specific Mathematica-related question?

Comment: Title is ambiguous.

Comment: You could use this to start you off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814011/mathematica-generate-a-list-of-primes-up-to-a-limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `Prime[ Range[ PrimePi[n]]]` (thanks to Artes suggestion below) to find all primes less than n, then used `IntegerDigits` on each, and looked for `5` using `Cases` then used `Position` to find the numbers themselves. I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this:

```
n=200;
list = Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]];
Cases[#, 5] & /@ (IntegerDigits@list);
p = Position[%, 5][[All, 1]];
list[[p]]  (*primes with 5 *)
(* {5, 53, 59, 151, 157} *)

Length[list] - Length[p] (*primes with no 5 in them)
(*41*)
```

Comment: `Prime[ Range[ PrimePi[n]]]` finds all primes `<= n`.

Comment: @Artes thanks. I knew there must be a better way to find primes less than N. Will update this part to use your method.